# How can I do a simple binary image classification in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, classification

I'm not really new to MATLAB, just new to this whole Machine Learning thing.

I have to do a simple binary image classification. I don't care if it's a toolbox or just code, I just need to do it. I tried a couple of classification codes I found online on Github or on other sites, but most of them worked randomly and some of them worked for pre-defined images.

Those that worked on pre-defined images were neat (e.g.: http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/events/cvml2011/materials/practical-classification/), but I had issues applying on a new set of images, just because there were some .txt files (vectors of the name of the images, which was easy to replicate) and some .mat files (with both name and histogram).

I had issues creating the name and histogram in the same order, the piece of code that I use is:

```
  for K = 1 : 4
    filename = sprintf('image_%04d.jpg', K);
    I = imread(filename);
    IGray = rgb2gray(I);
    H = hist(Igray(:), 32);
  end
  save('ImageDatabase.mat', 'I', 'H');
```

But for one reason or another, only the name and path of the last image remains stored (e.g. in this case, only image_0004 is stored in the name slot).

Another code that I found and it seemed easy was: https://github.com/rich-hart/SVM-Classifier , but the output is really random (for me) so if someone could explain to me what is happening I'd be grateful. There are 19 training images and 20 for test. Yet, if I remove one of the test images, 2 entries disappear from the Support Vector Structure?

Anyway, if you have a toolbox, or a more easy to adapt code or some explanations to the above codes, I'd be grateful.

Cheers!

EDIT:

I tried following the example of this code: http://dipwm.blogspot.ro/2013/01/svm-support-vector-machine-with-matlab.html

And even though I got 30 images of 100x100 I keep getting this error:

```
Error using svmtrain (line 253)
Y and TRAINING must have the same number of rows.

Error in Untitled (line 74)
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training_Set , train_label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
```

Comment: Depending on the images it is not surprising that your output looks random.
You need to have a lot more training samples.
If you have the machine learning toolbox I recommend working through Matlabs excellent [tutorial](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/getting-started-12.html).

Comment: The thing is that I don't have much time. This project was supposed to be worked on by some classmates, but they didn't manage to do anything in the end. I have to do everything alone and I have like 1 more day to go. Anyway, I edited my original post with something else. I'd enjoy if you'd be able to form an answer to it. Many thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you aren't resizing the training data correctly. It needs to be NxD where N is the number of samples (30 in this case) and D is feature dimension. If you are using raw images as features you need to reshape those from 100x100 to 1x10000 before using svmtrain. Also `train_label` should be an array of length N.

Comment: Could you share an example image. Maybe we can recommend another classifier. I doubt a SVM will work at all when trained with 20 images.

Comment: Thanks everyone for being so cooperative and helpful. It was because I was using an absolute path instead of the relative path (I'm talking about the link I posted after the latest edit). I got an output. Sometimes in the output I got the values 18 instead of 30 (how many images I used) and I don't really understand where to read which picture to what class is belonging. I used the same pictures for both training and testing just to see if it works (x-ray and radiography pictures). Printscreen of my SVM Struct output: https://i.imgur.com/KWv2dGv.png

Comment: Not all images are used as support vectors, but only those with the smallest margin. In your case its 18, without more information it seems fine to me. It is still not possible to train an 1000 dimensional input space with 30 data points.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. So as an interpretation to the SVMStruct is:

SupportVectorIndices: The vectors that were used as support (from the training set, 18 images were selected). SupportVectors (same as above). KernelFunction (linear classification). GroupNames (all thetrainign data).

But what about alpha and bias? Actually, where can I see exactly what vector to what class it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to train any classifier on raw 100x100 images, when you only have ~40 data points for training, testing and validation. So recommending a Matlab toolbox wouldn't really help your problem.

The answer is: Get more data

For completeness here are two approaches you could try:

**Feature extraction**

Maybe there are some very obvious features (some pictures are darker, have a white corner etc.) in your pictures, that you can extract *before* the training.  With 3-4 features you could try training a classifier with your data set. In this case I would try [fitcensemble](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcensemble.html) as it is very easy to use without the inner workings of the algorithm.

**Using a pre-trained classifier**

You can use **GoogLeNet** and maybe your pictures are fitting one of the ImageNet [categories](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/browse-synsets). Try [transfer learning](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/googlenet.html#d119e78281) if your images do not match any category.